ThreadPoolExecutor for Parallelism
I have PySpark code which does few POST API call to an external system.  For each row in the input dataframe, I need to trigger a POST API request (using Python code) to create an entry in an external system. Given that the dataset is large, this process was taking considerable time.
To improve performance, plan to use Python's ThreadPoolExecutor to process the rows (ie to POST APIs) in parallel (multi-threading) based on the available cores.
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, as_completed

num_cores = spark.sparkContext.defaultParallelism

def process_all_rows(input_df):
    results = []
    
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=num_cores) as executor:  # Adjust max_workers based on needs
        futures = {executor.submit(process_row, row): row for row in input_df.collect()}
        
        for future in as_completed(futures):
            try:
                result = future.result()
                results.append(result)  
            except Exception as e:
                logger.error(f"Error in thread execution: {e}")
    
    return results

While reviewing this, I was told that ThreadPoolExecutor mainly performs context switching. So if the input DataFrame has 100 rows and num_cores is set to 8 (ie. the cluster has 8 cores), the code will use only one core (not all available 8 cores), firing the POST requests sequentially with context switching ie. firing one POST API request, then the next and so on. Is this the correct understanding? Would the ThreadPoolExecutor uses all 8 cores in parallel.

As a general rule (there will always be exceptions), multithreading is preferred for I/O intensive operations whereas multiprocessing is optimal for CPU-bound activities. Thus the best technique in your case will depend on what process_row() does. If it's CPU-intensive then you won't make best use of your available CPUs due to Python's GIL

all process_row() does is creating an entry in external system via POST call.
